# Synchronizing Schema View and Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, database-project

1. DB_A -> DB project
2. DB_B -> Schema Comparison with DB Project
3. Apply Update Script to DB Project
4. Schema View shows changes, but Solution Explorer does not.

When applying changes during schema comparison, with database source and database project target, the changes are represented within the schema view, but the solution explorer still has all the old scripts, even though they've been dropped as a result of the schema comparison. Is this expected behavior?

How do I synchronize the Solution Explorer (and all its scripts) with the Schema View?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best answer I've found to this is:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vstsdb/thread/81c1d830-1921-47c0-87d5-c8cf27d35df6